# Site is not loading on normal browser but work in incognito mode

Tags: reactjs, azure, google-authentication

I am facing one issue where we have hosted the site on Azure but when we load it, it does not load and shows error

> "Access to resource at
>   'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=788183341030-htk2ipgs9ekkso8gpvrd4rst39klg7um.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fpatientcare.somatus.com%2F.auth%2Flogin%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=openid+profile+email&state=redir%3D%252Fmanifest.json%26nonce%3D02d3faf3d1d5425781d72e4b79d75746_20190605152218'
>   (redirected from 'https://patientcare.somatus.com/manifest.json') from
>   origin 'https://patientcare.somatus.com' has been blocked by CORS
>   policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the
>   requested resource."

But this works fine in incognito mode.

I have tried by enabling the option in Service Worker of Chrome Console "Upload on Cache."

Expected result is that is shows the Google Authentication page where is asks for the credentials.

Actual result is that it only shows the white screen.

Comment: just flush the cache? ctrl+f5?

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem. The problem is solved by:

- Disable Grammarly Extension.
- It's importance to remove/clean cache after that.

It work for my case.

Comment: This is happening on Client Side means on Prod. So can't tell Clients to do this when there are around 100 users.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is with chrome extensions. Please disable all the extension and try again.

Answer (score 0):

just disable Anti Tracker extension in your browser. It will solve.
same issue happened with me in Azure Portal, then I disabled Quick Heal Anti Tracker Extension.